# Type safety: The expression of type Xclass needs unchecked conversion to conform to Xclass<Yclass>

Tags: java

how to resolve this problem?
Type safety: The expression of type mResponseValue needs unchecked conversion to conform to `mResponseValue<mUserStatus>`

```
mResponseValue<mUserStatus> ResponseValue = Mobile.JSONtoClass(responseService, mResponseValue.class);
```

---

```
public abstract class Mobile {

 public static String ObjToJson(Object obj)
 {    
     Gson gson = new Gson();
       return gson.toJson(obj);
 }

 public static <T> T JSONtoClass(String strRequest,Class<T> type)
 {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     return gson.fromJson(strRequest, type);
 }
```

}

Comment: Using wildcard should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). When you call `Mobile.JSONtoClass(responseService, mResponseValue.class);` then the type parameter `T` will be substituted by `mResponseValue`, but you are assigning the return value to `mResponseValue<mUserStatus>` which results in an unchecked cast.

The problematic assignment can be split into two parts:

```
    mResponseValue rawResponseValue = = Mobile.JSONtoClass(responseService, mResponseValue.class);    // OK
    mResponseValue<mUserStatus> parameterizedResponseValue  = rawResponseValue; // Warning: Type safety ...
```

So, an easy solution could have been using `mResponseValue<mUserStatus>.class` as the second parameter of `JSONtoClass` call, but there is no such thing as `mResponseValue<mUserStatus>.class` during runtime since type arguments are erased.

To circumvent this problem, GSON provides methods which accepts [java.lang.reflect.Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html?is-external=true) which preserves generic type information as well. Using them, the warning could be eliminated as follows:

```
public static <T> T JSONtoClass(String strRequest, java.lang.reflect.Type typeOfT)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(strRequest, typeOfT);
}
```

then call like this:

```
TypeToken<mResponseValue<mUserStatus>> typeToken = new TypeToken<mResponseValue<mUserStatus>>() {};
mResponseValue<mUserStatus> responseValue = Mobile.JSONtoClass(responseService, typeToken.getType());
```

This solution prevents compiler warnings and actually fixes deserialization/serialization problems which can be caused by lost type information, see
 [Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types) in Gson User Guide for more.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't say anything about what he could/should do, which is what he asked...

Comment: The method fromJson(String, Class<T>) in the type Gson is not applicable for the arguments (String, Type)

Comment: @mirtiger make sure you are using `java.lang.reflect.Type`, I updated my answer to use qualified name for `Type`